# Vue3 testing composition API with vuex in vitest

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm having trouble getting a mock action to run using Vue3 while testing with vitest.

I have a component which calls out to a modularized vuex store that is imported into my component using the composition api. Something like the following.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { doAction } = useModActions([
      'doAction'
    ])
  }
})
```

I use `createNamespacedHelpers` to setup my store module from the vuex-composition-helpers library.

After I use `useStore` with a `Symbol` key to setup the state of my store. I consume it in my application by doing

```js
app.use(store, key)
```

To mock it in my tests I was trying the following

```js
   const actions = {
      doAction: vi.fn()
    }
    const spy = vi.spyOn(actions, 'doAction')
    const mockStore = createStore({
      modules: {
        mod: {
          namespaced: true,
          actions
        }
      }
    })
    const wrapper = mount(Component, {
      global: {
        provide: { [key]: mockStore }
      }
    })
```

But my spy is never called and my component always calls the original implementation. Is there a way to get all these pieces working together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mockStore` here (from Vuex's `createStore()`) is an instance of a Vue plugin, which should be passed to the [`global.plugins`](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-plugins) mounting option (not `global.provide`):

```js
// MyComponent.spec.js
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import MyComponent from '../MyComponent.vue'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('button calls doAction', async () => {
    const actions = {
      doAction: vi.fn(),
    }
    const mockStore = createStore({
      modules: {
        myModule: {
          namespaced: true,
          actions,
        },
      },
    })
    const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
      global: {
        plugins: [mockStore], // 
      },
    })
    await wrapper.find("button").trigger("click")
    expect(actions.doAction).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vitest-mock-vuex-module?file=src%2Fcomponents%2F__tests__%2FMyComponent.spec.js)

Comment: [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-vitest-mock-vuex-module-8ocecq?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue) shows an example of the original problem

Comment: That StackBlitz doesn't seem to exhibit any problems (i.e., the test passes), and there isn't a `useModActions()` in it. Can you update it to demonstrate the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hmm you are right, I will accept the answer since I can't demonstrate my problem with it. It must be something to my local setup. I'm not sure what the issue is right now.